# Python singleton pattern

Tags: python, singleton

someone can tell me why this is incorrect as a singleton pattern:

```
class preSingleton(object):
    def __call__(self):
        return self

singleton = preSingleton()

# singleton is actually the singleton

a = singleton()
b = singleton()

print a==b  

a.var_in_a = 100
b.var_in_b = 'hello'

print a.var_in_b
print b.var_in_a
```

**Edit:** The above code prints:

```
True
hello
100
```

thank you very much

**Part Two**

Maybe this is better?

```
class Singleton(object):
    def __new__(cls):
        return cls

a = Singleton()
b = Singleton()

print a == b

a.var_in_a = 100
b.var_in_b = 'hello'

print a.var_in_b
print b.var_in_a
```

**Edit:** The above code prints:

```
True
hello
100
```

Thanks again.

Comment: Could should show us the output of the print statements ?

Comment: Please use `id(a)` and `id(b)` to check the identity of the objects.  Please provide the actual output.

Answer (score 9):

Singletons are actually really simple to make in Python. The trick is to have the module do your encapsulation for you and not make a class.

- The module will only be initialized once
- The module will not be initialized until the first time it is imported
- Any attempts to re-import the module will return a pointer to the existing import

And if you want to pretend that the module is an instance of a class, you can do the following

```
import some_module
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.singleton = some_module
```

Answer (score 3):

Because this is not a singleton. Singleton must be single, your object is not.

```
>>> class preSingleton(object):
...     def __call__(self):
...         return self
...
>>> singleton = preSingleton()
>>> singleton2 = preSingleton()
>>> singleton
<__main__.preSingleton object at 0x00C6D410>
>>> singleton2
<__main__.preSingleton object at 0x00C6D290>
```

Comment: The `PreSingleton` isn't the singleton, the `singleton` is. You're misunderstanding the code.

Comment: no I didn't misunderstand. Neither are singletons. If you run the code like that twice, you will get different instances, period.

Comment: @Skilldrick `singleton` is an instance of `preSingleton`. It is not a class and hence cannot be said to follow Singleton pattern. Otherwise in that sense, every instance of a class is a singleton in itself.

Comment: I know, but when you 'call' `singleton`, it returns an object. If `singleton` were a class, and you 'called' it, it would return an object. To all intents and purposes, `singleton` is acting as a singleton.

Comment: Ok, then any variable is a singleton. You just get a value and it's always the same, whoa, singleton!

Comment: If you imagine that `singleton` is a class, then every time you instantiate it you get the same object. To me that fulfills the meaning of a singleton. Just because it isn't implemented with a private constructor and static methods and all that jazz, doesn't mean it's any less valid as an implementation.

Comment: @Skilldrick I can only partially agree. In it's current shape one can only *pretend* it's a singleton. If you clean the namespace (remove/overwrite the preSingleton), then it might become a real singleton, which does not invite creation of more of a kind.

Answer (score 2):

This is actualy the Borg pattern. Multiple objects that share state.

That's not to say there's anything wrong with it, and for most if not all use cases it's functionaly equivalent to a singleton, but since you asked...

edit: Of course since they're Borg objects, each instance uses up more memory so if you're creating tons of them this will make a difference to resource usage.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sexy little singleton implemented as a decorator:

```
def singleton(cls):
    """Decorate a class with @singleton when There Can Be Only One."""
    instance = cls()
    instance.__call__ = lambda: instance
    return instance
```

Use it like this:

```
@singleton
class MySingleton:
    def spam(self):
        print id(self)
```

What happens is that outside of the class definition, `MySingleton` will actually refer to the one and only instance of the class that exists, and you'll be left with no mechanism for creating any new instances. Calling `MySingleton()` will simply return the exact same instance. For example:

```
>>> MySingleton
<__main__.MySingleton instance at 0x7f474b9265a8>
>>> MySingleton()
<__main__.MySingleton instance at 0x7f474b9265a8>
>>> MySingleton() is MySingleton
True
>>> MySingleton.spam()
139944187291048
>>> MySingleton().spam()
139944187291048
```

Comment: Elaborating strategies for implementing singleton classes in Python is just like trying to sell ice-creams in Murmansk in the middle of January. "Singletons" are simply realized by creating a module instance... please have a look at the explanation from unholysampler above.

Comment: I disagree, using module has some disadvantages. For example, if you want to share state between two methods in your singleton, you'd then need to do that with a module global variable, which gets ugly (functions wanting to set that variable would have to call `global your_variable`). Also, I have a number of small singletons that I use for different purposes. They're much nicer to define as a few classes in a single module rather than all separate modules, because they're just too small to stand as modules on their own.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the problem (if it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck...). Looks like a singleton to me.

It works differently from a Java singleton (for example) because Python uses the same syntax to call a function as to create a new instance of an object. So `singleton()` is actually calling the singleton object, which returns itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with your class:

```
>>> class preSingleton(object):
...     def __call__(self):
...         return self
...
>>> x = preSingleton()
>>> y = preSingleton()
>>> x == y
False
```

So, more than one instances of the class can be created and it violates the Singleton pattern.

Comment: `preSingleton` isn't the singleton, `singleton` is.