# Singleton across modules

Tags: python, design-patterns, singleton

I'm trying to implement a Singleton and I am running into difficulty when I import the module. My set up is the following. I am using Python 2.7.

#### MODULE 1

```
class SingletonClass(object):
    def __new__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self._instance:
            self._instance = super(SingletonClass, self).__new__(
                                self, *args, **kwargs)
        return self._instance

print SingletonClass()  #OUTPUT: 0x00000000030F1630
print SingletonClass()  #OUTPUT: 0x00000000030F1630 (Good, what I want)
```

#### MODULE 2

```
import SingletonClass

class AnotherClass:
    print SingletonClass.SingletonClass() #OUTPUT: 0x0000000003292208
```

Within the module the singleton is working, but in another module the Singleton is not returning the same object as it did in the first. Any idea why?

#### Edit

For now I will put the only thing that I have found that works. I'm sure there is a better solution to this, but I think this may better convey what the underlying problem is.

#### MODULE 1

```
class SingletonParent(object):
    _instance = None

    def __new__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self._instance:
            self._instance = super(SingletonParent, self).__new__(
                                self, *args, **kwargs)
        return self._instance
```

#### MODULE 2

```
import SingletonParent    
class SingletonClass(object):
        def __new__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if not SingletonParent.SingletonParent._instance:
               SingletonParent.SingletonParent._instance = super(SingletonClass, self).__new__(
                            self, *args, **kwargs)
            return SingletonParent.SingletonParent._instance 

    print SingletonClass()  #OUTPUT: 0x00000000030F1630
    print SingletonClass()  #OUTPUT: 0x00000000030F1630
```

#### MODULE 3

```
import SingletonClass

class AnotherClass:
    print SingletonClass.SingletonClass() #OUTPUT: 0x00000000030F1630
```

## Solution (Edit 3)

Lesson: Don't have your main function in the same module as your Singleton!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python singleton pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037914/python-singleton-pattern)

Comment: There's no way that what you have there can possibly work, by which I mean you'll get an error either at the `import` or the `SingletonClass()` in the second module. Also, why's the `print` statement inside a class definition? This code does not make any sense.

Comment: @kindall This is pseudo code. It's roughly what I have, but I was trying to simplify things for readability.

Comment: So… The code you posted works: `<a.SingletonClass object at 0x10bef8e10>
<a.SingletonClass object at 0x10bef8e10>
<a.SingletonClass object at 0x10bef8e10>` — could you post some code that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: @DavidWolever I think the problem lies in the way I am organizing my modules. The way that I have it now each module has its own version of the object. I'm not sure why you would be getting different results. I should point out that I am using Python 2.7. Also, when I created a new module and class called SingletonParent and let SingletonClass be the sole importer of it everything works. I'd prefer to avoid this implementation if possible though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is most likely that the module is being imported twice under two different names.

To test for this, add something like:

```
print "Being imported..."
```

In `module1.py`.

If this message is printed twice, then the module is being imported twice, and that's your problem. To fix it, make sure that you're using the same name to import the module everywhere[0], and that you're not doing hackery with `sys.path`.

[0]: Technically this shouldn't be necessary, but it's a simple fix.

Comment: It does print twice, but I'm not sure where my problem is. In Mod1 I import Mod2 and Mod3. In Mod2 and Mod 3 I import Mod1. Is this bad practice?

Comment: Then that's your problem. You can find out where it's being imported from using `import traceback, sys; traceback.print_exception(*sys.exc_info())`, which will print a traceback.

Comment: And if you've got a circular import (`mod1` importing `mod3`, `mod3` importing `mod1`), then there must be something you aren't mentioning, because that should be impossible (unless one of the modules only imports the other from inside function, or otherwise defers the import somehow).

Comment: I think this is the core of my problem. I'm coming from a Java/C++ world where this is common. Mod1 has class A which is a singleton, which uses class B which I house in Mod2. class B must use some of the functionality of the singleton.  In this case Mod1 must import Mod2 and Mod1 must import Mod1. I do this for readability. Both are large classes and it's easier if they are separated out.

Comment: That doesn't really address my statement, though — there must be something you're not mentioning, then, because circular imports are *impossible*.

Comment: Hm. I'm not sure what I could be leaving out. In mod1 I have import mod2. In mod2 I have import mod1. I run mod1's main which simply creates a new class A.

Comment: Could you pastebin the exact import lines?

Comment: Aha! The problem was that I was having my main method in the same class as the singleton. I moved this to its own file and it solved the problem. Thanks for all your help David!