# Does python ever multiply-load a module?

Tags: python, python-import

I'm noticing some weird situations where tests like the following fail:

```
x = <a function from some module, passed around some big application for a while>

mod = __import__(x.__module__)
x_ref = getattr(mod, x.__name__)
assert x_ref is x  # Fails
```

(Code like this appears in the pickle module)

I don't think I have any import hooks, reload calls, or sys.modules manipulation that would mess with python's normal import caching behavior.

Is there any other reason why a module would be loaded twice? I've seen claims about this (e.g, https://stackoverflow.com/a/10989692/1332492), but I haven't been able to reproduce it in a simple, isolated script.

Comment: What does `assert x_ref == x` say ?

Comment: also False, but I think actually *calling* the function always gives the same result

Comment: Do those modules have `__file__` attribute? Test for them to see if it is exactly the same module.

Comment: I'm not sure how to test that, since `x.__module__` gives a string and not a module object. I can print `__import__(x.__module__).__file__`, but I don't know what to compare that to

Comment: I thought I had seen some weird cases in the past with imports different ways...i.e. user would do `import x.y`, then `x.y.something()`, and then another function would do `from x import y` and then `y.something_else()`, and the second one wouldn't see the result of the first one. but I can't reproduce it now....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you misunderstood how [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) works:

```
>>> from my_package import my_module
>>> my_module.function.__module__
'my_package.my_module'
>>> __import__(my_module.function.__module__)
<module 'my_package' from './my_package/__init__.py'>
```

From the documentation:

> When the name variable is of the form `package.module`, normally, the
>   top-level package (the name up till the first dot) is returned, not
>   the module named by name. However, when a non-empty `fromlist`
>   argument is given, the module named by name is returned.

As you can see `__import__` does **not** return the sub-module, but only the *top* package. If you have `function` also defined at package level you *will* indeed have different references to it.

If you want to just load a module you should use [`importlib.import_module`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html?highlight=importlib#importlib.import_module) instead of `__import__`.

---

As to answer you actual question: AFAIK there is no way to import the same module, *with the same name*, twice without messing around with the importing mechanism. However, you could have a submodule of a package that is also available in the `sys.path`, in this case you *can* import it twice using *different names*:

```
from some.package import submodule
import submodule as submodule2
print(submodule is submodule2)   # False. They have *no* relationships.
```

This sometimes can cause problems with, e.g., `pickle`. If you pickle something referenced by `submodule` you cannot unpickle it using `submodule2` as reference.

However this doesn't address the specific example you gave us, because using the `__module__` attribute the import should return the correct module.

Comment: Thanks for the extra information. I'm still a bit mystified about the particular failure, but I suspect it has to do with the last code snippet you posted